# Why does RAD throw a compile error on IOException(ex);

Tags: rad, java-6

Why does RAD7 give a compile error of

> The constructor IOException(Exception) is undefined

on the following line

```
throw new IOException(ex);
```

The Javadoc for Java 1.6/6.0 states that `IOException` has a [`IOException(Throwable)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) constructor

When I look at the definition of `IOException` I see only the following constructors

- `IOException()`
- `IOException(String)`

**Notes:**

- Rational Application Developer 7.0.0.8
- Project Compatability set to Java 6

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your project being set to compile against an older JRE.

If this is a "faceted project" (right-click the project -> properties, choose "Project Facets" if it exists), then your "Java" facet is probably not 1.6.

If this is not a "faceted project", go to the project's build-path and you'll see that it's compiling against a WAS 6.0 JRE which is JDK 1.4. Double-click it to change to WAS 7.0 JRE.